# Remote Debug jbpm processes (including workitems code)

Tags: wildfly, jbpm, wildfly-10

I'm trying to find a way of debugging my jbpm processes. These processes include many custom work items handlers (some of them are asynchronous, completed via Rest Api).

Can anyone suggest me how to procede?

Thanks,
Laura

Comment: Hi @Laura ,have u found some  way to set up remote/local debug for jbpm processes?

Comment: Nope :( Do you have any idea?

Comment: Debugging WorkitemHandler is normal java debugging which i can do remote debug for them.But for bpmn process itself i don't have solution yet